# How do I dynamically change Padding or margin in flutter

Tags: flutter

To dynamically change heights and widths I use:

```
final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

Container(
      height: screenSize.height*0.45,
       width: screenSize.width*0.45,

   ),
 ),
```

My question is how can I dynamically change padding and margin, so that the layout would look the same on different sized screen, or should I also use screenSize with padding and margin? This is how I use it now

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 10),
```

Comment: Sorry your question isn't clear to me, add more detail what you're trying to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing right now is that there will be a padding of 10 pixels from top and 10 pixels from left side of the screen. So that the Container might have bigger or smaller shapes on different screen sizes. You can do it dynamically by using the screenSize values and media query so that you set the padding according to the screen size:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenSize.height*0.1, left: screenSize.width*0.1),
```

The result of the code above will be a padding of 10% of the height of the screen from top and 10% of the width of the screen from left. That’s how you can set your padding dynamically. ( Also be aware that you cannot use `const` keyword if you’re using mediaQuery values as the value is not available at the compile time.

Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a) article.